# MongoDB query, filter using cursor

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections, one that has _id and UserId, and another that has UserId (same unique identifier) and "other data".

I want to filter the latter collection based on a list of _ids from the former collection.

Can someone provide an example query for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to 'join' collections in MongoDB is a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation stage (available in version 3.2).

```
firstCollection.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: {$in: [1,2,3] }}}, // filter by _ids
  {
     $lookup:
     {
        from: "secondCollection",
        localField: "UserId",
        foreignField: "UserId",
        as: "data"
     }
  }   
])
```

That will add 'data' field to the documents from the first collection which will contain all related documents from second collection. If relation is not 1:1, you can add [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage to flatten results:

```
   {$unwind: "$data"}
```

Comment: Is there anything I can do if I'm using version 2.6.9?

Comment: @AlexWu nothing on db side. You can only do two queries - first to get UsesrIds by _ids. And second to get data by UserIds